# using Variables inside callbacks

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

question from a javascript newbie. How could I sturcture this callback function differently, so I could use request.object inside this callbacks.

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Calendar", function(request) {
    CallSomeOtherFunction(null, {
        success: function(user) {
            request.object.save();
        },
        error: function(user, error) {
            alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: You are able to use `request` in that way already, as long as it contains a property named `object`, are you experiencing errors or similar to make you think otherwise?

Comment: You can use them already.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I am missing somthing else then, because I am not getting it inside there. Can I ask some other question. What if I would start modifying request.object before CallSomeOtherFunction and inside CallSomeOtherFunction. How can I make sure both values are saved, but not overwritten?

Comment: Thank you guys! Of course it was a typo in the end :-(